# save user to db,if I have two customusers.How do i save them and generate JWT using SimpleJWT in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I Have two Customusers in my project,

The main Customuser:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,null=False)

    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', null=True, blank=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)

    total_tickets_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total_tickets_bought = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    kyc_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    social_media_account = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    bank_account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    bank_account_iban = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    bank_account_name_on_card = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    user_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    delete_account_request = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    account_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('buyer', 'Buyer'),
        ('seller', 'Seller'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default='buyer')
    ACCOUNT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('suspended', 'Suspended'),
        ('banned', 'Banned'),
    )
    account_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ACCOUNT_STATUS_CHOICES, default='active')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, related_name='customuser_set')
    # user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, blank=True, related_name='customuser_set')

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

**And also i have another custom user for saving the users which are registering on my website using Bank Credentials(From the bank API page)**

I want to save the Bank user and give an access token as a responce when the user logs in.
I have the JWT auth and I am using SimpleJWT,so in documentation I got an info that I can give the token to user manually,I tried to do it but it gives me this error:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
        user_data = response_data.get("userData", {})

        user = BogUser(
            firstName=user_data.get("firstName"),
            lastName=user_data.get("lastName"),
            birthDate=user_data.get("birthDate"),
            pin=user_data.get("pin"),
            identityDocument=user_data.get("identityDocument"),
            sex=user_data.get("sex"),
            citizenshipCountry=user_data.get("citizenshipCountry"),
            birthCountry=user_data.get("birthCountry"),
            birthPlace=user_data.get("birthPlace"),
            homeAddress=user_data.get("homeAddress"),
            actualAddress=user_data.get("actualAddress"),
            photo=user_data.get("photo"),
            phone=user_data.get("phone"),
            mail=user_data.get("mail"),
        )

        user.save()
        auth_user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=user.id)
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(auth_user)

        # https: // django - rest - framework - simplejwt.readthedocs.io / en / latest / creating_tokens_manually.html
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }`
```

**it gives me "expected type 'AuthUser', got 'BogUser' instead " error on this line -> "            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
" **,

I have read some solutions,but in those solutions they say you have to have a relationship between those two auth models.But i don't want to have the relationships because they don'y have the same fields inside.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_path.AuthUser'` in your `settings.py` and you are trying to generate the token with the `BogUser`, you can either have a field in your `BogUser` called `auth_user`(or whatever) and then generate the token with `bog_user.auth_user` here `refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(bog_user.auth_user)` or go and check your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and customize it based on your needs as you didn't specify your needs or your `BogUser`.

Here is some great article to have a look: [link](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/topics/auth_user_model/)